# What's the shape of electric field line in a rectangular metal under varying magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory

We know that,the shape of electric field line in a cylinder under varying magnetic field is circle,and I wonder,what's the situation if it is a piece of metal with rectangular cross section?
I think it might be something like superellipses.Can somebody tell me is it true or how to treat this problem?
Thank you！

Comment: Well, I didn't know that... what I do know is that that's only a near field approximation. The question for the true shape inevitably leads us to having to solve Maxwell's equations for a physically realizable antenna.

Comment: The electric field is due to changing vector potential which would be in the same or opposite direction of the current.  The electric field is essentially the short range part of an electromagnetic wave called the Fresnel region.  If the conductor wasn't there it would be circular.  The metal will attenuate the wave because currents will be induced giving rise to inductance and resistance which will complicate the problem. You could try solving for the vector potential(Dalambertian of A = charge plus current density) but handling the source side of equation might be difficult.

Comment: [link](http://www.usna.edu/Users/physics/mungan/_files/documents/Scholarship/InducedElectricField.pdf) A satisfying answer might be found here.